# Selector with set of objects

Tags: java, playframework, twirl

I am using the play framework and trying to create a selector from a set of objects with no luck. for example, I have the following company class which has

```
public class Company {
        private Set<TaxRate> taxRates;

    public void setTaxRates(Set<TaxRate> taxRates) {
            this.taxRates = taxRates;
        }

    public Set<TaxRate> getTaxRates() {
            return this.taxRates;
        }
}
```

and in my TaxRate class I have the following,

```
  public class TaxRate {
    private BigDecimal percentage;
    private Boolean isDefault;

    public TaxRate(BigDecimal percentage, Boolean isDefault) {
        this.percentage = percentage;
        this.isDefault = isDefault;
    }

    public BigDecimal getPercentage() {
        return this.percentage;
    }

    public Boolean getDefault() {
        return this.isDefault;
    }

    public void setPercentage(BigDecimal percentage) {
        this.percentage = percentage;
    }

    public void setDefault(Boolean aDefault) {
        this.isDefault = aDefault;
    }
}
```

Now in my controller I fill the form with the company object `form.fill(company)`

and in my view i've tried the following

```
@repeat(companyForm("taxRates"), min = 0) { taxRate =>
                   @select(companyForm(taxRate.name.toString +".percentage") , options(Seq("0","5","20")), '_label -> "Default VAT Rate")
               }
```

The selector is not rendered on the page, not sure why. Since in my db there are values. If anyone can help that would be much appreciated Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like play framework doesn't actually create the selector because the object it self is null. So after create the new tax rate object with some initial values, the selector is created on the view.